# Big boss attend my development meeting randomly to review me?

Tags: professionalism

Some background - I am a placement student (12 month intern) at a corporate company. I am 8 months into my placement. We have monthly dev/scrum meeting about progress and projects. 
This month a big boss of the company attended my meeting this was unexpected. He said he attends these meeting to most student. I showed some power bi dashboards I created and he asked if I could teach his department. He said he will book a 1 hour!!! meeting to discuss somethings with me it seems like he will talk about my professionalism i.e presenting skills however said my developement skills are good.Does it seem like I am going to get fired from today meeting?

Comment: If he asked you to teach his department, isn't that a good thing?

Comment: He is a non tech guy I am a student developer. So its nothing special. I am worried since the department manager seemed worried and asked big boss to speak privately about why he came?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite the opposite.

The rarest commodity a big boss has is his time.  The fact that he's willing to spend a whole hour with you says something.

He also mentioned having you teach his department.  People who are about to be fired do not get asked to teach.

Relax, and congratulations on making a good impression with the boss.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am not sure when I showed him the power bi daahboard he said if I could train his team. However my supervisor asked about confirming my end date which is in 3 months and asked if I had any holiday planned either an offer and extension of my contract or waiting to get rid of me. I think big boss will comment about my bad presenting/professionalism but I am worried? Should I leave before getting fired

Comment: DON'T LEAVE.  You are doing well - better than most interns.  Having doubts is perfectly normal at your point in your career, but you really need to ignore them for the next 6 months or so.

Comment: Should I email him and say thanks for his time. Also mention I would be happy to for him to provide feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Executives generally don't book an hour of their time to fire an intern. Especially if they do not manage you directly. Executives also generally avoid booking their time for anything they don't see as important. He certainly wouldn't ask you to teach his team if you weren't doing something very right. It's more likely that he sees potential in you and feels he can teach you a few things that will help you in the long run, and that's really good for you because...

**As an intern, the main reason you are there is to learn.** An hour w/ an executive is a *fantastic* opportunity to learn and grow, regardless of whether the feedback is positive or negative. And since this is likely someone who has spent time in a boardroom, they could potentially teach you a lot about presentation skills (if they so choose). And even if the meeting goes poorly, you will likely be able look back on it in the future and realize that you learned something important that has helped you in your career. Don't worry about the meeting, go into it eager for the opportunity to learn.